# Repost from a past life?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I posted a question awhile ago on StackExchange before I deleted my account. Some time later, I decided to get a new account. While doing this, I discovered that my old account was still alive although it had lost all of its points.

At any rate, I'd like to repost an old question which is still up but under a different name (User#...). How do I repost the question without seeming like I stole someone else's work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flag that question for moderator attention, choose "other" and give your explanation.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help.